# How to correctly store data based on Id in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, authentication, save, crud

I have a table called Diaries in my DB which is linked to my Users table. A user can have many Diaries but a diary can only belong to one user.

I want to save data to a row in my Diaries table based on user id. When a users logs in, he can fill a form which calls the save method to save to the row in Diaries corresponding to that user.

I'm using Laravel's Auth.

```
public function save(Request $request)
    {

$id = Auth::id();
$error = $request->error;
$fix= $request->fix;


$diary = new Diary();
$diary->error = $error;
$diary->fix=$fix;
$result = $diary->id->save;

if($result==true)
{
    echo "saved";
}else{
    echo "not saved";
}
```

Comment: Compare with example from [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method). You are using id but you should use complete model.

Comment: you should also specify the user_id for the diary before saving it like this: $diary->user_id = $id or $diary->user_id = Auth::id();
and be sure that Diary $fillable field contains user_id. Also you have to change $result = $diary->id->save; to $result = $diary->save();

Answer (score 0):

```
public function save(Request $request)
    {
$result = $request->user()->diaries()->create([
'error' => $request->error,
'fix' => $request->fix,
]);

// you should have "diaries" relation in User model and setup fillables for Diary

if($result==true)
{
    echo "saved";
}else{
    echo "not saved";
}
```